# How select optimum combination of vectors to minimise similarity function using python?

Tags: python, optimization, vector

I have a function which can take a list of vectors of length n where each vector in the list can have a different length as well. This function is as follows:

```
def get_similarity(FP):
fps = FP
sim = []
for n in range(len(fps)):
    inputs = product([fps[n]],fps)
    result = list(starmap(jaccard_index, inputs))
    result.remove(1.0)
    sim.append(np.mean(result))
return np.mean(sim)
```

My vectors could be for example:

```
    FP = [
[66, 1627, 1659, 1896, 1899, 832, 1357, 1659, 321, 1102, 1658, 1869, 1882],
    [68, 1373, 1611, 1659, 1896, 1899, 1658],
     [305, 319, 1372, 1597, 1659, 1896, 1899, 1659, 575, 1101, 1373, 1658, 1882],
     [306, 1372, 1597, 1659, 1896, 1899, 1356, 1659, 561, 1086, 1373, 1658, 1882],
     [307, 1372, 1597, 1659, 1896, 1899, 1356, 1659, 561, 1086, 1373],
     [319, 335, 1373, 1597, 1659, 1896, 1899, 1659, 575, 1101, 1373, 1658, 1882],
     [319, 573, 1373, 1597, 1659, 1659, 830, 1101, 1373, 1658, 1882],
     [320, 1373, 1611, 1659, 1896, 1899, 1117, 1659, 575, 846],
     [335, 830, 1372, 1597, 1659, 1896, 1899, 1659, 576, 1101, 1373, 1658, 1882]
]
```

I would like to be able to find the best combination of these vectors which would minimise the value I get from `get_similarity(fps)` function. What is a good way of going about this?

Caveat: The total number of vectors I am dealing with is huge ranging 100k - 1 million, I've only showed a fractional percentage here. So the solution must be able to scale up - or have some method for chunking etc.

Please help.